# Accessing private variables from within a closure

Tags: php, scope, closures

I'm trying to reference a private variable of an object from within a closure. The code below would seem to work, but it complains `Fatal error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active in test.php on line 12` and `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in test.php on line 20`.

Any ideas how to accomplish the same results using a closure while keeping the variables private and without making helper functions (defeating the whole idea of a private variable).

```
class MyClass
{

    static private $_var1;
    private $_var2;

    static function setVar1( $value )
    {
        $closure = function () use ( $value ) {
            self::$_var1 = $value;
        };
        $closure();
    }

    function setVar2( $value )
    {
        $closure = function () use ( $value ) {
            $this->_var2 = $value;
        };
        $closure();
    }

}

MyClass::setVar1( "hello" ); //doesn't work

$myclass = new MyClass;
$myclass->setVar2( "hello" ); //doesn't work
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit to note,** this answer was originally meant for **PHP5.3** and earlier, it's possible now. For current information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18116422/179104).

---

This is not directly possible. In particularly, closures have no associated scope, so they cannot access private and protected members.

You can, however, use references:

```
<?php
class MyClass
{

    static private $_var1;
    private $_var2;

    static function setVar1( $value )
    {
        $field =& self::$_var1;
        $closure = function () use ( $value,  &$field ) {
            $field = $value;
        };
        $closure();
    }

    function setVar2( $value )
    {
        $field =& $this->_var2;
        $closure = function () use ( $value, &$field ) {
            $field = $value;
        };
        $closure();
    }

}

MyClass::setVar1( "hello" );

$myclass = new MyClass;
$myclass->setVar2( "hello" );
```

Comment: @Dave I was actually writing it before I read your answer. Anyway, +1 for you as a settlement :p

Comment: Heh. Speedy parallel development. Thanks for the +1, and returned in kind as you put far more effort in than I! :-)

Comment: You could also use `Closure::bind` as in my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52701638/1163000

Answer (score 4):

This is possible starting in PHP 5.4.0

```
class test {
    function testMe() {
        $test = new test;
        $func = function() use ($test) {
            $test->findMe();        // Can see protected method
            $test::findMeStatically();  // Can see static protected method
        };
        $func();
        return $func;
    }

    protected function findMe() {
        echo " [find Me] \n";
    }

    protected static function findMeStatically() {
        echo " [find Me Statically] \n";
    }
}

$test = new test;
$func = $test->testMe();
$func();        // Can call from another context as long as 
            // the closure was created in the proper context.
```

Comment: Just to clarify, would that work also for `private function findMe()`?

Answer (score 2):

Closures have no concept of `$this` or `self` -- they are not tied to objects in that way. This means that you would have to pass the variables through the `use` clause... something like:

```
$_var1 =& self::$_var1;
$closure = function() use ($value, &$_var1) {
  $_var1 = $value;
};

$_var2 =& $this->_var2;
$closure = function() use ($value, &$_var2) {
  $_var2 = $value;
};
```

I haven't tested the above code, but I believe it to be correct.

Comment: That's not correct, at least not in 5.4. See: http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php