# Does PHP have lexical scope in anonymous functions / closures?

Tags: php, closures, lexical

I'm using PHP 5.4 and wondering if the anonymous functions I'm making have lexical scoping?

I.e. If I have a controller method:

```
protected function _pre() {
    $this->require = new Access_Factory(function($url) {
        $this->redirect($url);
    });
}
```

When the Access Factory calls the function it was passed, will the $this refer to the Controller where it was defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anonymous functions don't use lexical scoping, but [`$this` is a special case and will automatically be available inside the function as of 5.4.0](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). Your code should work as expected, but it will not be portable to older PHP versions.

---

The following will **not** work:

```
protected function _pre() {
    $methodScopeVariable = 'whatever';
    $this->require = new Access_Factory(function($url) {
        echo $methodScopeVariable;
    });
}
```

Instead, if you want to inject variables into the closure's scope, you can use the `use` keyword. The following **will** work:

```
protected function _pre() {
    $methodScopeVariable = 'whatever';
    $this->require = new Access_Factory(function($url) use ($methodScopeVariable) {
        echo $methodScopeVariable;
    });
}
```

---

In 5.3.x, you can get access to `$this` with the following workaround:

```
protected function _pre() {
    $controller = $this;
    $this->require = new Access_Factory(function($url) use ($controller) {
        $controller->redirect($url);
    });
}
```

See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391099/using-this-in-anonymous-function) for more details.

Comment: Ah, good to know it's different in PHP5.4 (which still hasn't reached my Debian Stable packages yet... might need to install it manually).

Comment: Do I need a "use ($this)" or does 5.4 automatically give you access to $this?

Comment: 5.4.0+ automatically binds `$this`. Check out [this short video](http://youtu.be/-Ph7X6Y6n6g) explaining it.

Comment: Of course it uses lexical scoping. Every programming in common use today uses lexical scoping. `$this` is a special variable and has special meaning.

Comment: @newacct: In PHP functions are not lexically [scoped](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), at least not according the definition of that term which I'm familiar with. They're "sealed off" from surrounding scopes and can only access or affect variables inside themselves, (super)globals, and `$this`/`self`/`parent` (if defined within a class), unless extra variables are explicitly bound with `use`. See [this demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/5518331).

Comment: Yeeeech, selective closure! What a ghastly concept. Someone in PHPland should be shot.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no, but you can access *public* methods & functions by passing it:

```
$that = $this;
$this->require = new Access_Factory(function($url) use ($that) {
    $that->redirect($url);
});
```

**edit:** as Matt rightly pointed out [support for `$this` in closures started with PHP 5.4](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)