# finally exception gives an error php

Tags: php, exception

I am trying to learn PHP, and i just moved to Exceptions and when i
try a example from

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

`Example #2 Exception handling with a finally block`

And i get an error

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\filename.php on line 13`

```
<?php
function inverse($x) {
    if (!$x) {
        throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
    }
    else return 1/$x;
}

try {
    echo inverse(5) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
} finally {
    echo "First finally.\n";
}

try {
    echo inverse(0) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
} finally {
    echo "Second finally.\n";
}

// Continue execution
echo 'Hello World';
```

Comment: Are you using PHP 5.5 or greater?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: finally block is supported by php 5.5 or higher

Comment: For a workaround, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/927236/1726343

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `finally` block of try-catch was added in PHP 5.5 which is still in development so the likely reason it isn't working for you is because you are using PHP 5.4 or earlier.

You won't be able to use finally unless they backport it into an earlier PHP version or you are on a 5.5 release.

Comment: Okay thanks i was using 5.4.4 and help me try closing this question