# What's the `finally` keyword for in PHP?

Tags: php, try-catch-finally, finally

Consider these two examples

```
<?php
function throw_exception() {
    // Arbitrary code here
    throw new Exception('Hello, Joe!');
}

function some_code() {
    // Arbitrary code here
}

try {
    throw_exception();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

some_code();

// More arbitrary code
?>
```

and

```
<?php
function throw_exception() {
    // Arbitrary code here
    throw new Exception('Hello, Joe!');
}

function some_code() {
    // Arbitrary code here
}

try {
    throw_exception();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} finally {
    some_code();
}

// More arbitrary code
?>
```

What's the difference? Is there a situation where the first example wouldn't execute `some_code()`, but the second would? Am I missing the point entirely?

Comment: `Code within the finally block will always be executed after the try and catch blocks, regardless of whether an exception has been thrown, and before normal execution resumes.`

Comment: I think this is related on this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031515/can-i-use-try-catch-finally-like-this

Comment: Just to save anyone else copy-pasting from the PHP manual, I have read that but don't understand the difference between these two examples, otherwise I wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: See the RFC doc: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/finally

Comment: *sidenote:* finally block is available at PHP5.5+

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you catch Exception (any exception) the two code samples are equivalent. But if you only handle some specific exception type in your class block and another kind of exception occurs, then `some_code();` will only be executed if you have a `finally` block.

```
try {
    throw_exception();
} catch (ExceptionTypeA $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

some_code(); // Will not execute if throw_exception throws an ExceptionTypeB
```

but:

```
try {
    throw_exception();
} catch (ExceptionTypeA $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} finally {
    some_code(); // Will be execute even if throw_exception throws an ExceptionTypeB
}
```

Comment: Worth a +1 for citing a specific instance when `some_code()` will not be executed

Comment: I have spent a while researching why they are at all useful, and finally (no pun intended), your answer gives a valid reasoning for the necessity of a finally block.

Answer (score 0):

fianlly block is used when you want a piece of code to execute regardless of whether an exception occurred or not...

Check out Example 2 on this page :

[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Answer (score 0):

Finally will trigger even if no exception were caught.

Try this code to see why:

```
<?php
class Exep1 extends Exception {}
class Exep2 extends Exception {}

try {
  echo 'try ';
  throw new Exep1();
} catch ( Exep2 $e)
{
  echo ' catch ';
} finally {
  echo ' finally ';
}

echo 'aftermath';

?>
```

the output will be

```
try  finally 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exep1' in /tmp/execpad-70360fffa35e/source-70360fffa35e:7
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /tmp/execpad-70360fffa35e/source-70360fffa35e on line 7
```

here is fiddle for you. https://eval.in/933947

Answer (score 0):

From [the PHP manual](http://php.net/exceptions):

> In PHP 5.5 and later, a *finally* block may also be specified after or instead of *catch* blocks. Code within the *finally* block will always be executed after the *try* and *catch* blocks, regardless of whether an exception has been thrown, and before normal execution resumes.

See [this example in the manual](http://php.net/exceptions#example-281), to see how it works.

Answer (score -2):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWj60p8esD0

**Watch from:** 12:30 onwards

Watch this video.
The language is JAVA though.
But i think it illustrates Exceptions and the use of **finally**  keyword very well.

Comment: Thanks soden, that explains what I already know, i.e. that it runs regardless of whether there's an exception. But so does code placed after the block, doesn't it? Is there a specific advantage to having it as part of the block?

Comment: Depends on how much you want the exception to be abstracted from the user. Generally speaking using finally is a rarity.